# converting date to different format

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Ok this one has been asked a million times but I can't find any answer to work for me.  I have a column named 'Invoice Date' that is data type 'date'.  I have an excel pivot chart that uses my query to update itself every 60 mins. Everytime this updates I lose my cell formatting and what's weirder, is that when I format the cells in excel to ie: Mar-14 then nothing happens, until I double click in each cell, then it displays correctly.  This is vital because I need to group by months, and this is the only way I have been able to do this.

I have another date field in the query that is 'smalldatetime' and when formatting the cells in excel I just select the column, and format and all cells change without me double clicking.  So I'm thinking maybe if I can convert the data in my SQL query to display the date similar to 'smalldatetime' that my pivot will work properly.

I have tried the checking of boxes in excel that CLAIM to preserve cell formatting... this obviously doesn't work for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There are a variety of functions available in sql server that you can use to extract just the year and month from a date.  One of those might be suitable for this situation.

Comment: I'm a newb, would you mind pointing me in the right direction for a function to extract the year/month?  I have been looking to solve this for couple days now trying various options and non has worked.

Comment: Also I think formatting was wrong initially.  Because this also worked:    convert(smalldatetime, [mycolumn]) as 'my column'

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following SQL in your SELECT statement:
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),YourDateColumn,106)
the end result will be "02 Apr 2014".
You should be able to do so for smalldatetime type of column as well.

Comment: But that will change the date correct???  Everything I have found on here only returns today's date, when I need the same date returned but in a different format.

Comment: Sweet. Glad I could help. Mark as answer? Cheers!